# How to change color of textbox when value exceed the max of char

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textboxes whose width varies, let us suppose that the maximum no of visible character in a textbox are 10. now I want that when the user enters more than 10 char the color of the textbox is changed.

To check all the values the user has to hover his mouse on it.
so how do I change color of textbox based on the given condition.

Thanks
or
Please tell me how to find no of visible characters in a textbox

Comment: Adding that if it is related to `size`  or `maxlength` of an input box will help you in finding an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with jQuery it can be solved by the following:

html

```
<input type="text" name="textField" title="textField" value="asdfasdfasdf"  />
```

(jquery)javascript

```
$('input[type=text]').mouseover(function () {
                    if($(this).val().length > 10)
                    {
                        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
            });
```

I don't really know about the "no of visible" characters.

Comment: Quotes are mandatory for your selector. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ . So: `$('input[type="text"]').mouseover()`

Comment: @PeeHaa - I didn't know that. I've always done it without the quotes and never had any issues. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript to do this.

Check the length of the the string in the textbox.  If length > 10 then change the background color of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Javascript.

One question though!

Do you want to count spaces as char? or do you want to only count char with out space?

```
<script>
function checkLength(textField) {
 var strText = textField.value;
 // if without spaces
 strText = strText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

 if(strText.length > 10) {
  textField.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
 } else {
  textField.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
 }
}
</script>

<input type="text" name="sometextfield" onkeyup="checkLength(this);" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have just assumed that let it be 10 character but in actual I dont know I have set the width in pixel It has to be done dynamically provide me that script

Comment: He is concerned about visible area or size of the text box not the maxlength of characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little bit of research to dynamically change the count as the user is typing, but here is a good way to start:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getCount()
{
document.getElementById("txtCount").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML.length;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="txtCount">Mouse over the sun and the planets and see the different descriptions.</p>
<textarea id="myText" cols=60 rows=3 onmouseover="getCount();">hello</textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Open a new text file and copy the above code and save it with an HTML extension then open it with the browser, and just hover the mouse pointer over the textarea, you will notice that a

text changes with the count of the characters inside the textarea control.

Comment: May be something I didnt tell u my mistake
I m filling these value from database and sometimes on the page as well, I want the color of the textbox should be changed even if I m not moving my mouse. This is to let user understand that the text in the textbox is more than he can see